Can I use the suffix -consuming to create whatever word meaning "consume a lot of sth"?
time-consuming: requiring a lot of time
What about energy-consuming, resource-consuming,...?
Do these words (and others formed in the same way) exist and follow this concept? Can I use the suffix -consuming to create whatever word meaning "consume a lot of sth"?

Perhaps not for any noun (not all things can be consumed), but your examples are valid, and in common use. However, that is an example of a hyphenated word, not of a suffix. In the word "consuming," ing is the suffix.
Recently, the phrase all-consuming desire has become increasingly popular... a bit clichéd.

I felt all-consuming desire in 1966, aged 14, when I saw Jane Birkin in the film  Blow-Up.

@MichaelHarvey, plainly, you were ahead of the curve ;-)

She was very beautiful, but pencil-thin. What I really liked was that she was cool.
